# What is difference between .bb ( recipe ) and .bbclass ( class ) in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I just started understanding Yocto. I have not find much information about classes ( .bbclass ) files . I know .bb file is a recipe which contains the instruction to build a package. When do we have to write a recipe and when a class or what is the difference between both

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yocto classes (.bbclass) are used to factorise recipe's code, to handle some general problems. For instance, handling CMake in recipes is made in cmake.bbclass so that when you add `inherit cmake`, your recipe will manage CMake specifics.

You can look at class list in [manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes) too.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a best practice about naming? Can I have my-recipe.bb and my-recipe.bbclass with the same basename? Or will that mess up with includes when including from a different recipe?

Comment: @MartinH. not sure but i'll probably avoid it. Btw, your class name should be more generic than your recipe name?

Comment: @Nayfe my thought was I have a framework that is needed to compile other recipes. So I have a recipe for my framework and a class to include python code into recipes using the framework. Maybe like cmake.bb and cmake.bbclass in the original question.